# How can I pass parameters through RXJS chain?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have an array with 3 items :

```
arrActions: Array<Item> = [{ url: 'http://1.com', data: '5' }, 
                           { url: 'http://2.com', data: '6' }, 
                           { url: 'http://3.com', data: '7' }];
```

I want to execute an Ajax request for each item. That's no problem . But I also need to know which item am I dealing with in the `subscribe` callback.

This is what I tried :

```
 from(this.arrActions).pipe(
      mergeMap((i) => this.ajaxAlike(i)))
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
      });
```

This returns :

[image]

But I don't know to which request each callback relates to.

So I thought maybe this  :

```
from(this.arrActions).pipe(  
      mergeMap((i) =>(of({data:i.data, url: this.ajaxAlike(i.url)}))))
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
      });
```

But now , the http is not executing :

[image]

And besides ,I think I'm going the wrong way here.

[**Online demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-client-8lbrge?file=app/app.component.ts)

**Question:**

How can I invoke all urls , and at `subscribe`, get both `http` result + `item` itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just map each result after you receive it:

```
from(this.arrActions)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((i) => this.ajaxAlike(i)
      .pipe(
        map(result => ({ data: i.data, result })),
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
  }, err => {
    console.log(' error which is ->', err);
  });
```

This will print the following output:

```
{data: "5", result: "httpResponse"}
{data: "6", result: "httpResponse"}
{data: "7", result: "httpResponse"}
```

You updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-client-y43j1w?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks. :) ( btw , I didn't want to put angular tag , becuase imho it's pure related to rxjs . no ? )

Comment: Aha, ok no problem